# Append URL param value into html

Tags: javascript, css, html, url

To extract that user name from URL into html

Sample url

```
something.com?editors=username
```

Html code

```
<P id="demo"><p>
```

JS:-

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"Welcome " + get_editor() + " to my website";

function get_editor() {
  var url = new URL( window.location.href );
  var params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
  return params.get('editors');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on fact that this is GET parameter you can do it like that:

```
(function() {
  var url_string = window.location.href;
  var url = new URL(url_string);
  var editors = url.searchParams.get('editors');
  var htmlElement = document.getElementById("element");
  htmlElement.innerHTML += editors;
})();
```

Where in your case your **searchParams** is **n**.

After you get this element you can easily append your html code.

**EDIT** I've added example with appending html element.

Comment: Lets assume that your element in html has id "super", so firstly you have to get this element ( var element = document.getElementById("super) ), then to append you need to - element.inerHTML += editors (this var based on my example) or to replace it - element.inerHTML = editors.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am late, but from Czeran's answer, I created this JS function that will append and go to the URL:

```
    function urlAppend(value){
        var current_location = window.location.href;
        current_location += "/" + value;
        window.location.href = current_location;
    }
```

This allows for a more dynamic URL append

Hope this helps!