# How to pass text from inputtext to URL?

Tags: javascript, html, django-urls

I want to pass text of input, `id = "u_name"` to the form action url.

```html
<form  id = "ismForm" action = {% url 'polls:todo'  %} method="get" >
    <input type="text" id = "u_name" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="text" name="pass" />
    {% csrf_token%}
    <input type="submit" name="click" value="Register" />
     />

</form>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015475/append-url-into-html Might help, not sure - need some more details.

Comment: What is it passing currently? Is the stray `/>` a typo? Did you mean to have the csrf_token floating between elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a listener on the form for submit. On submit add the `u_name` value to the `action`.

```
const form = document.getElementById("ismForm");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  //check to see if the form is valid before doing this...
  this.action += `?u_name=${form.querySelector('#u_name').value}`
})
```

No need to do `e.preventDefault()` as the goal is to let the form submit be handled by the navigator.

Working example: ( `e.preventDefault()` is required to see `console.log` output)

```js
const form = document.getElementById("ismForm");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  this.action += `?u_name=${form.querySelector('#u_name').value}`
  console.log(this.action);
})
```

```html
<form  id = "ismForm" action ="/some/url" method="get" >
    <input type="text" id = "u_name" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="click" value="Register" />
</form>
```